# Unable to write to the file, Created in java using File class

Tags: java, file-handling

Class `MakeDirectory` contains the constructor, and in the constructor I created a directory and inside that directory I created a file. But I am unable to write anything to the newly created file, even though the file and directory have been generated successfully. Can anyone help me figure out why I am not able to write to the file Anything.txt?

```
public class MakeDirectory {
    MakeDirectory() throws IOException{
        // Creates Directory
        File mydir= new File("MyDir");
        mydir.mkdir();

        // Creates new file object
        File myfile = new File("MyDir","Anyfile.txt");

        //Create actual file Anyfile.txt inside the directory
        PrintWriter pr= new PrintWriter(myfile);
        pr.write("This file is created through java");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        new MakeDirectory();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: i did not get any error. file has been generated successfully under that specific directory but when i see the file Anything.txt i always find it empty. containing no word or string.

Comment: can we see your code witch you use to write inside this file?

Comment: above mentioned code is the actual code sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `PrintWriter` you need to know that it is not automatically flushing.  After you `write` you need to `flush`.  Also, don't forget to close your `PrintWriter`!

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myFile);
pw.write("text");
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

An approach available in Java 7 employs the try-with-resources construct. Using this feature, the code would look like the following:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("myFile")) {
    pw.write("text");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: sir... You made my day..finally i got the answer... and it worked ... Would you like to elaborate it more. why do we need to flush and close mandatorily for PrintWriter not for other classes such as FileWriter etc etc

Comment: Absolutely, you have to flush because until you do the text is sitting in a buffer.  Once you flush that buffer, the text gets printed in the file.  With classes like `FileWriter` the class is designed to call that function automatically on write.

Comment: ohhh so nice...i would be keeping this thing in my mind...thanks and stackover flow is fantastic. i got the solution from the veterans of the java in no time. Thanks once again sir. You are doing such a good job and making us understand the concepts of java. I am new here so could not resist myself for expressing my gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

With `BufferedWriter` you can just write the strings, arrays or characters data directly to the file:

```
void makeDirectory() throws IOException {
    // Creates Directory
    File mydir = new File("MyDir");
    mydir.mkdir();

    // Creates new file object
    File myfile = new File("MyDir", "Anyfile.txt");

    //Create actual file Anyfile.txt inside the directory
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myfile.getAbsoluteFile()));
    String str = "This file is created through java";

    bw.write(str);
    bw.close(); 
}
```

Comment: sir i tried it but newly created file is still empty. nothing is being written inside the file.

Comment: I tested it and it creates a txt file with a `String str` value text inside.

Comment: sir i forgot to add on the statement close and after adding the bw.close it worked for me as well... thanku so much

Comment: when you do `close()` it automatically flushes  the data from buffer.

Comment: yes sir. Thank you so much ... Keep helping me. I am new to java. Need support people like you who are happy to help others always